# Can't bind to 'items' since it isn't a known property of 'tree-view'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

Implementing nested tree view in ionic but this error shown even the library is correctly referenced and added in imports.

**App.Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
 // Import library
import { IonTreeViewModule } from 'ionic-tree-view';


 @NgModule({
 declarations: [AppComponent],
 entryComponents: [],
 imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), 
 AppRoutingModule,IonTreeViewModule],
 providers: [
 StatusBar,
 SplashScreen,
 { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
   ],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
 export class AppModule {
```

}

**HomePage**

```
   export class HomePageModule {

   public items = [ ]  ;
   public persistedName = "";
   public treeViewName = "";
   constructor(){
this.items = [ { "id":1, "name":"features" }, { "id":2, "name":"Add", "parentID":1 }, { "id":3, "name":"Remove", "parentID":1 }, { "id":9, "name":"Update", "parentID":1 }, { "id":11, "name":"UpdateDel", "parentID":9 }, 
{ "id":27, "name":"Add", "parentID":2 }, { "id":28, "name":"master" } ]  ;
   this.persistedName = "MyItemsPersisted";
   this.treeViewName = "MyItemsTreeView";
  }
```

**HomePage.html**

```
  <ion-content>
  <div class="ion-padding">
The world is your oyster.
<p>If you get lost, the <a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://ionicframework.com/docs/">docs</a> will be your guide.</p>
  </div>
  <tree-view [items]="items" [persistedName]="persistedName" 
   [treeViewName]="treeViewName"></tree-view>

</ion-content>
```

**Error**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As stated on npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-tree-view), you need to import your module as `IonicTreeViewModule.forRoot()`

Answer (score 0):

You've misspeled your import dependency its IonicTreeViewModule not IonTreeViewModule.

Comment: I did not ,actually the library class name exist with Ion not ionic , its a writing mistake on author's end. Class with name Ionic does not exist in this library you may search yourself

Comment: Tryed it with IonTreeViewLibModule?